# Android - Install apk to mobile through wifi network

Tags: android

I am new in android and working an android application now.

Here i am asking an option to install apk on my mobile while building the application.

I need to install apk to mobile through wifi, Is it possible, if yes the how?

Please see my scenario,

1-I need to build the project from the android  studio

2-apk automatically need to install on mobile

3-mobile and system should be connected to a single wifi network

Answer (score 2, accepted):

step 1:- go to the folder of your sdk/platform-tools and open cmd at this path

step 2:- type **adb tcpip 5555**

step 3:- find the IP address of your android device with **adb shell netcfg**

step 4:- type **adb connect DEVICE_IP_ADDRESS:5555**

> Note:- Keep your device connected with your pc using datacable while
>   this process. After this you can disconnect your device.

After this process you can debug or run your app wirelessly via wifi.